# Getting custom variable value from Google Tag Manager into Google Analytics issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to get some server side error messages in google analytics using google tag manager. I managed to push some data in my `dataLayer` and I'm getting this:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event':'error_event_nl',
    'eventCategory': 'errors',
    'eventAction': 'starter_action',
    'eventLabel': 'error-messages-label',
    'error_messages_data':[ 
            {
                'original_message':'Server side error in English Version',
                'translated_message':'Server side error inDutch Version'
            }
    ]
});
```

My event is  fired, see img:
[image]
and with data:
[image]

My question is how can i see in Google Analytics the value of the custom variable (from google tag manager) : `errors_messagesData` or from js script: `error_messages_data` ?

In google analytics I receive the values from `eventCategory`, `eventAction` and `eventLabel`. See img:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Data Layer Variables in GTM: `error_messages_data.original_message` and `error_messages_data.translated_message`.

And create 2 hit-level custom dimensions in GA, remember indexes.

Send these Data Layer Variables with events to GA using *Custom Dimensions* in tags:

[image]

Now you can add these dimensions to standard reports as a second dimension or use in custom reports.

Comment: thnx , interesting idea :)